# Hide tabs in workshop module

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have some tabs in a workshop module and some filters on left, based on the selected filter I want to hide some tabs.

I tried to replace tabs with buttons and I can hide buttons based on filters and on button click I can show relevant tab but the problem with buttons is I cannot see which button is selected as we can see with tabs.

**UPDATE**

***Resolved*** (I don't know how to mark it resolved)

Palantir has added a new widget called "tabs" that allows most customization including the visibility of particular tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Palantir has added a new widget called "tabs" that allows most customization including the visibility of particular tabs.

Documentation - [Workshop - Tabs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/widgets-tabs/)